# GetProcAddress an Class object without header file

Tags: c++, class, dll, getprocaddress

It should be possible to get an class object from an dll without the corresponding dll header file!? But how can I make the typedef of the class for GetProcAddress without known type from header file?

Have you an example?!

Thanks and greets,

leon22

Comment: Do you mean the class definition instead? With a `typedef` you define a new name for an existing type or an aggregate of types, like `typedef int Array[3];`

Answer (score 0):

`GetProcAddress` gives you the address of a function. When you have the full decorated name of a C++ class member function, you can get the address of it. With the same information you can get the signature of the method with the `undname` utility.

But you will need the header file to get class definition itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the types involved, you can't call a function, and that's pretty much the end of that.

Comment: You can use Dependency Walker for names and types!

Comment: @leon22: isn't that the answer you your own question then?!

Comment: HI! No, because I can't typedef my class object without known type from header file (maybe there is a way with void*)!?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the address of an object (i.e. an instance) in the DLL. GetProcAddr won't give you that, but it can give you the address of a function that can, in turn, give you the address of the object, if such a function exists in the DLL. if that function has extern "C" linkage, there won't be any name mangling either.

Comment: I have already that dll function and it works fine, but when we make any changes in the header file we must recompile the whole project!